# would have been/would be

Tags: modal-verbs, present-perfect, present-tense

> I wish everyone was beautiful in this world. And nobody **would have been** ugly like me.

I have a doubt concerning the second sentence.

1. *And nobody **would be** ugly like me.*
2. *And nobody **would have been** ugly like me.*

Can anyone suggest to me which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: "I wish everyone was beautiful" refers to the present time, so why use a  past tense for the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say

> I wish everyone were beautiful in this world. Then nobody would be as ugly as I.

In a way, you have a possible conditional clause there:

> If everyone were beautiful in this world, nobody would be as ugly as I.